# Add style to a Data template

Tags: wpf

I have the following Data template with triggers:

```
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCalled}" Value="Yes">
            <Setter TargetName="labelNumber" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            <Setter TargetName="labelNumber" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter TargetName="labelNumber" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCalled}" Value="JustCalled" >
            <Setter TargetName="labelNumber" Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
       </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>

</DataTemplate>
```

Rather than individually set the label properties I want to call a style like the below:

How would  get the Data Template to use the style above.

thank you

Comment: Style i want to add:
<Style  x:Key="myLabelStyle1"  TargetType="{x:Type Label}">        
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
          </Style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a setter like

```
<Setter TargetName="labelNumber" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource myLabelStyle1}" />
```

but you'll need to make sure you're not setting any properties locally on the labelNumber Label because they'll override any Style settings. You'll need another Style for your Label to set any properties for its default state in addition to the ones in the Triggers.

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource myDefaultLabelStateStyle}"/>
```